# Cast UIButton in UITableViewCell to custom class not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have created a custom toggle button class which inherits from UIButton. I added the button to the UITableViewCell on the storyboard and assigned the class "LmxStartStopToggleButton" in the Identity Explorer's Custom -> Class section. For the UITableViewCell I created also a Custom Class "LmxRijtijdTableViewCell" and ctrl-dragged to the IBOutlet "rijtijdBtn"

```
@property IBOutlet LmxStartStopToggleButton *rijtijdBtn;
```

of the @interface of this class. All working fine.
But after that I want to manipulate the appearance of the button from within the UITableViewCell on initialization. Runtime it appears not to be of type "LmxStartStopToggleButton" but of type UITableViewCellContentType and I can't cast to it. How can I call a function on the button if it can't be cast? Or why isn't it of the correct type initially if I set it in the  Identity Explorer?

```
LmxStartStopToggleButton *btn = ((LmxStartStopToggleButton *)self.rijtijdBtn);
```

[image]

Comment: So what's your question? What issue is this causing for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have another element in your cell pointing to "rijtijdBtn."

If that's not the problem, make sure that the button is of type "LmxStartStopToggleButton" by clicking on the button in the interface editor, going to the 3rd tab from the right on the right tool bar and then making sure under "Custom Class" it says "LmxStartStopToggleButton."

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I needed! The first cell was pointing to another element indeed. I was already thinking this was not possible in iOS.